# Error: Cannot find module "../Models/User" in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: node.js, module, gitlab, pipeline

I am constructing the pipeline. When i run these tests in vs code, it all works perfectly, but it doesn't work in the pipeline for some reason.
´´
Pipeline Error:

```
$ npm run build-test-server
> stava@1.0.0 build-test-server
> cd server && npm install && npm test
added 640 packages, and audited 641 packages in 18s
63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
> stava_server@1.0.0 test
> node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.js tests/api.js --exit --timeout 5000 && jest --testPathPattern=server/tests --runInBand --detectOpenHandles
Tue, 28 Feb 2023 22:25:52 GMT express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option at index.js:50:3
Error: Cannot find module '../Models/User'
Require stack:
- /builds/tdt4140-2023/landsby-1/gruppe-10/stava/server/Controllers/userController.js
- /builds/tdt4140-2023/landsby-1/gruppe-10/stava/server/Routers/userRouter.js
- /builds/tdt4140-2023/landsby-1/gruppe-10/stava/server/index.js
- /builds/tdt4140-2023/landsby-1/gruppe-10/stava/server/tests/api.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
```

etc.

Comment: '../Models/User' file is missing, I guess.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but the file exists. I am able to run the script locally in vscode.

Comment: There is not enough info